# Finding the rank of $T: \mathbb R_{2}[x]\to \mathbb R^{4}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$\forall p(x)\in R_{2}[x],T: \mathbb R_{2}[x]\to \mathbb R^{4}$ is defined by:

$T(p(x))=\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 \\p(1)+p(-1) \\p(2)+p(-2) \\p(3)+p(-3)\end{matrix} \right] $

I need to find the rank of $T$ and I want to make sure I've done it correctly:

for any $p(x)=ax^{2}+bx+c$ we get: $T(p(x))=\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 \\2a+2c \\8a+2c \\18a+2c\end{matrix} \right] $.

We define the identity tranformation $I: \mathbb R_{2}[x]\to \mathbb R^{4}$ in order to simplify things.

for $\ker T$, we solve $A\vec v=\vec 0$, where $\vec v=I(p(x))$ and $A=\left[ \begin{matrix} 0& 0& 0 \\2 &0 &2 \\8 &0 &2 \\18 &0 &2\end{matrix} \right] $.

we get $\ker T=\textrm Span\{ bx\} $, thus $\dim \textrm Im T=2$.

Is it right? if so, was it the most efficiant method? and If not, where was I wrong? I'm not quite sure what to do when $T: V\to W$ but $\dim V\neq \dim W$...

Comment: By $\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ do you mean the space of quadratic polynomials with real coefficients?

Comment: @ConnorHarris yes, I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way basically works. More concisely: $\{p_0 = 1, p_1 = x, p_2 = x^2\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}_2[x]$. $T p_0 = (2, 2, 2, 2)$, $Tp_1 = (0, 0, 0, 0)$, and $T p_2 = (0, 2, 8, 18)$; there are two nonzero vectors here, and clearly neither is a scalar multiple of the other, so $T$ has rank 2.

Comment: Yes! you just reminded me to apply the tranformation for a base, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}_2[x]$: since
$$
T(1)=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}
\quad
T(x)=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
\quad
T(x^2)=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 8 \\ 18 \end{bmatrix}
$$
the matrix of the linear map with respect to $\{1,x,x^2\}$ and the canonical basis is
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\2 & 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 & 8 \\ 2 & 0 & 18 \end{bmatrix}
and a standard Gaussian elimination
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\2 & 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 & 8 \\ 2 & 0 & 18 \end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\2 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 6 \\ 0 & 0 & 16 \end{bmatrix}
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
shows the rank is $2$. Also $T(1)$ and $T(x^2)$ form a basis of the image.

Since $T(x)=0$ and the kernel has dimension $1$, $x$ forms a basis of the kernel.

Comment: the last matrix you wrote is (almost) the canonical representaion of T, right?

Comment: @gbi1977 Not sure what matrix you're referring to.